# Use pulldata from a Survey123 feature layer and use it to generate next feature number

Tags: arcgis-survey123, arcgis-survey123-connect

I am trying to make a smart form on Survey123 connect. I have a field name feature ID. I am trying to save this featureID on Survey123 when we submit the survey. After that I want to use this featureID to pulldata and use it to populate next feature ID number for my new survey.

For example... let's suppose I have submitted a survey with featureID - "ABC100", now I want to use this featureID to auto-populate in my next draft survey as "ABC101".

Comment: What have you tried?  What research have you done?  What went wrong?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried pull data Layer which would work definitely, for now i am trying to figure it out how? i am still stuck to generate automatic number by retrieving last entered ID